# free() gives me an error invalid conversation from chat to void

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I am learning stuff about dynamic memory and trying to write some code. However whey I try to run it it outputs an error and I cannot solve the mistake. There must me something wrong with malloc() usage but I am not sure.

The error points here -> free(cube[c][b][a]);

Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM 4

void showCube(char**** cube, int dim) {
  int a, b, c;
  for(c = 0; c < dim; c++) {
    for(b = 0; b < dim; b++) {
      for(a = 0; a < dim; a++) {
        printf("%c ", *cube[c][b][a]); 
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("50*-\n");
  }
}

int main() {
  char*** cube = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**) * DIM);
  int a, b, c;
  for(c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {
    cube[c] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**) * DIM);
    for(b = 0; b < DIM; b++) {
      cube[c][b] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * DIM);
      for(a = 0; a < DIM; a++) {
        cube[c][b][a] = ((a + b + c) % 26) + 'A'; 
      }
    }
  }

  showCube(&cube, DIM);

  for(c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {
    for(b = 0; b < DIM; b++) {
      for(a = 0; a < DIM; a++) {
        free(cube[c][b][a]); 
      }
      free(cube[c][b]);
    }
    free(cube[c]);
  }
  free(cube);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it self-explanatory? `cube[c][b][a]` is `char` and not a pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What do I need to fix in code to make it work properly?

Comment: Since `DIM` is a compile-time constant, why mess with dynamic allocation at all?  Just declare cube in `main` as `char cube[DIM][DIM][DIM];` and avoid both `malloc()` and `free()` altogether.  You can use the same type for function parameters accepting that type, too, which will fix one of the errors in `showCube()`.

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate space for the array, you allocate memory at three levels:

```
  char*** cube = (char***)malloc(sizeof(char**) * DIM);
  int a, b, c;
  for(c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {
    cube[c] = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char**) * DIM);
    for(b = 0; b < DIM; b++) {
      cube[c][b] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * DIM);
      for(a = 0; a < DIM; a++) {
        cube[c][b][a] = ((a + b + c) % 26) + 'A'; 
      }
    }
  }
```

But try to free it at 4 levels:

```
  for(c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {
    for(b = 0; b < DIM; b++) {
      for(a = 0; a < DIM; a++) {
        free(cube[c][b][a]); 
      }
      free(cube[c][b]);
    }
    free(cube[c]);
  }
  free(cube);
```

`cube[c][b][a]` is a `char`, not a `char *`, so you can't free it.  Get rid of the innermost loop.

```
  for(c = 0; c < DIM; c++) {
    for(b = 0; b < DIM; b++) {
      free(cube[c][b]);
    }
    free(cube[c]);
  }
  free(cube);
```